# Dublin Core metadata - Describing document in two languages

Tags: html, dublin-core

In Dublin Core, as example, how can I express the document title in two language?

From what I have found I could:

```
<meta name="dc.language" content="en">
<meta name="dc.language" content="fr">
<meta name="dc.title" content="English Title">
<meta name="dc.title" content="Titre en français">
```

But, is there a way to specify witch title is in witch language as (my own invention):

```
<meta name="dc.language" content="en">
<meta name="dc.language" content="fr">
<meta name="dc.title" content="English Title" language="en">
<meta name="dc.title" content="Titre en français" language="fr">
```

**Edit:**
After some more research in directions given by comments and answers. [I found](http://dublincore.org/documents/dc-xml-guidelines/), that this is look my answer (Recommendation 9):

```
<dc:subject xml:lang="en">seafood</dc:subject>
<dc:subject xml:lang="fr">fruits de mer</dc:subject>
```

And that the dc.language should only be the language that my document is published.

Comment: So you have both English and French words on your website? Or can you change from English to French and vice versa?

Comment: This is more metadata for describing a document in a document management system. But I need to describe the document in two languages.

Comment: You make me realize that probably I'm not heading in the right direction. Because, if I declare two dc.language, it means that my document should be in those two language... witch is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

HTML defines the [`lang` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/dom.html#the-lang-and-xml%3alang-attributes).

```html
<meta name="dc.title" content="English Title" lang="en">
<meta name="dc.title" content="Titre en français" lang="fr">
```

Comment: Thanks! But I search something that meet Dublin core specifications.

Comment: @jeb: What do you mean by "meet"? If you use Dublin Core in HTML, using `lang` *is* the way to specify the language of property values (when you use other formats, there are other ways). For HTML, see some examples in [Expressing Dublin Core metadata using HTML/XHTML meta and link elements](http://dublincore.org/documents/2008/08/04/dc-html/).

Comment: @Jeb Alternatively, you could look at RDFa where you'd be defining RDF triples of the form `<document> dc:title "English Title"@en` and `<document> dc:title "Titre en français"@fr`. Those values are _literals_ with _language tags_, which seems to be the sort of thing that you're looking for.

Comment: @unor You're right, but it wasn't clear in my question, but I want to express metadata for a document in XML. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Link to Generate DC.Meta tags : http://www.dublincoregenerator.com/generator_nq.html